Ignore collision between parent objects in order to detect collision between its child game objects


If weapon collided with the body deal damage, if weapon collided with other weapon do not deal damage.

Problem is that when two weapons collide it detects it as if Player object and Goblin object collide and not that actual weapons collide.

I have tried:

to add and remove rigid bodies.
to extract children from Player game object because somehow weapon collision box becomes part of a player and i cannot get weapon to weapon collision.




 public class ObjectDamage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int damage;
    public int team;
    public float bounceForce = 5f;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {   
        Debug.Log($"Collided with object with tag: {collision.gameObject.tag}"); 
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == 3)
        {
            ClashWithOtherWeapon();
            Debug.Log("Reached!");
            return;
        }

        ObjectHealth objectHealth = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ObjectHealth>();
        if (objectHealth != null && objectHealth.team != team)
        {
            objectHealth.TakeDamage(damage);
            BounceEnemyBack(collision);
        }
    }

    private void ClashWithOtherWeapon()
    {
        return;
    }

    private void BounceEnemyBack(Collision2D collision)
    {
        Rigidbody2D rb = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (rb != null)
        {
            Vector2 bounceDirection = collision.transform.position - transform.position;
            bounceDirection.Normalize();
            rb.AddForce(bounceDirection * bounceForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}


can you show your code?

What object is this script attached to?

To Weapon game object

Do the weapons have thier own rigidbodies?

When i tried putting rigid bodies on weapons they didn't follow Player game object anymore like they used to

I did @iBeMeltin i feel like problem is in organization of my objects and components or settings of some attributes in rigid bodies

You should check collision.collider, which represents the Collider2D component that collides with the current object.
And collision.gameObject refers to the game object where the Rigidbody2D associated with the collider is attached.

Very grateful for your help.
